# UiSearchBar for Maps like address search using Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uisearchbar

I have a map included in my app and I would like to integrate a search for addresses.

I wonder how apple did the trick to show the map and then switch to the UiTableView (containing the search result)

I have a ViewController holding the map. This can't hold a UiTableView the same time, so how can I provide a result list within the same view?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [UISearchController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/index.html), it has its own tableview to show the results of the searches.

Comment: mhm. Do you have any tutorials on this? I have seen this, but don't know how to use the internal tableView.

Comment: I would suggest this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Yes, I just found this. Thanks.